# MEF issue on some machines, but not on others

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I have a .NET 4.0 project which I was asked to modify. The project uses MEF to load needed functionality @ runtime.

This functionality is offered in form of a dll, which within the solution has it own project.

I have added 4 new project, basing myself on the same template as the one used for the other dll's.

Within another part of the application all dll's are loaded in the following fashion:

```
var exporters = Directory.GetFiles(ImporterConfig.GetInstance().ExporterPluginsPath, "*.Exporters.*.dll");

foreach (var exporter in exporters)
{

    catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.LoadFile(exporter)));

    AddConfigurationToConfigFile(exporter);
}
```

On my machine when I try to run my modifications aren't kiaded. Strangely enough, on other machines it does.

I can't seem to find a difference what could explain it.

Anyone here who have an idea?

Comment: Are you running in Visual Studio or just double click executable?  If running executable you probably have to public and run the setup.exe file that is generated with publish. The Net library or dll's on on your PC is probably different from the PC where software was built.

Comment: Did you make sure the dlls in question are properly outputted to the plugin path on your machine?

Comment: I'm running the app from within Visual Studio. Yes, the dll's are being created in the correct directory. I can see they are being found, but for some reason they're not loaded, but I'm not getting an error. when the app tries to load them